# re-add your handler on every postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

when the page is loaded the following code is invoke

### page load

Dim products As New LinkButton

products.Text = "Products"

testPanel.Controls.Add(products)

### AddHandler products.Click, AddressOf getProducts

### getProducts function

Dim testDb As New Product

```
Dim arr As ArrayList = testDb.DbLoop()

Dim ObjList As ProductBo

Dim ID As Integer
Dim link As LinkButton



For Each ObjtList In arr

    ID= ObjtList.C_Id
    link = New LinkButton
    testPanel.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
    link.ID = ID
    link.Text = ObjList.Name
    link.CommandArgument = CustInt
    Me.testPanel.Controls.Add(link)
    AddHandler link.Click, AddressOf getProductsDetails
Next ObjList
```

---

what i want to achive when the page load i link is create Products when i click on products link it invoke an event handler call getProducts. getproducts will loop in the database to fetch all record then it will creat a link for each product name when i click on the product name it should invoke another event. my problem is how can i re add control after every postback thank u

Answer (score 0):

Because the links are dynamically created, you have to re-create and re-add the handler for them on each postback.

On the _init event, you have to check the state you are in (before product load or after product load), then create either the Product Load link OR the Product Details link.  Key is they have to be created EVERY postback AND they have to be created before the _Load event.  Typically this should be done on the _Init event.

Something along the lines of this:

```
        Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    If ViewState.Item("ProductsLoaded") IsNot Nothing Then
        If ViewState.Item("ProductsLoaded").ToString = "True" Then
            GetProducts(Me, New EventArgs)
        Else
            CreateProductsButton()
        End If
    Else
        CreateProductsButton()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Private Sub CreateProductsButton()
    Dim btnProducts As New LinkButton
    btnProducts.Text = "Products"
    testPanel.Controls.Add(btnProducts)
    AddHandler btnProducts.Click, AddressOf GetProducts
    ViewState.Item("ProductsLoaded") = False.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub GetProducts(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' get products list here
    ' and set handlers for each link
    ViewState.Item("ProductsLoaded") = True.ToString

End Sub

Private Sub GetProductsDetails(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'get product details here
End Sub
```